# How can I change the label color of a Dropdownsearch widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Dropdownsearch widget and the default label color is black but I want to change it to grey. How can I do this? This is my Dropdownsearch widget. The problem is that the Dropdownsearch does not have a property called labelStyle which most widgets do.

```
                    Container(
                      child: Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(
                          textTheme: TextTheme(
                            subtitle1: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: height * .024),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: DropdownSearch<String>(
                          label: "Primary Industry",
                          mode: Mode.BOTTOM_SHEET,
                          showSearchBox: true,
                          maxHeight: height * .5,
                          dropdownSearchDecoration: new InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            prefixIcon: const Icon(
                              Icons.corporate_fare,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          showAsSuffixIcons: true,
                          showClearButton: false,
                          dropdownButtonBuilder: (_) => Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                              size: height * .04,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ),
                          showSelectedItem: true,
                          items: _industry,
                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropDownValue = newValue;
                            });
                          },
                          selectedItem: dropDownValue,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have my Laptop with me so I cant try it myself but look [here](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search) for the right properties...maybe `popupBackgroundColor`